# alertdialog tries to open more than once

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

When the game is over it is supposed to open an alertdialog saying game is over and what score you got. It does this but more than once and it keeps opening dialogs until the app crashes. I cannot figure out why it is doing this. The logcat isnt't reporting an error either. I tried putting the code that opens the dialog in try{} and that made it work sometimes but not consistently. Do you guys have an idea what is causing the problem?

Here is the relevant code.

```
class SnakeView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

public SnakeView(Context context, Point size){
    super(context);
    handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());

    mContext = context;

    mScreenWidth = size.x;
    mScreenHeight = size.y;

    mBlockSize = mScreenWidth / NUM_BLOCKS_WIDE;
    mNumBlocksHigh = ((mScreenHeight)) / mBlockSize;

    loadSound();

    mHolder = getHolder();
    mPaint = new Paint();

    mSnakeXs = new int[200];
    mSnakeYs = new int[200];

    startGame();
}
public void updateGame(){
    if (mSnakeXs[0]== mMouseXs && mSnakeYs[0] == mMouseYs){
        eatMouse();
    }

    moveSnake();
    if (detectDeath()){
        mSoundPool.play(mDead_sound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setTitle("Game Over!")
                .setMessage("Your score: " + mScore + "!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("New", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, SnakeActivity.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Start.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                alertDialogBuilder.show();
            }
        });


    }


}
private void runOnUiThread(Runnable r){
    handler.post(r);
}

  }
```

Comment: Seems like you are calling `updateGame()` method multiple times .Debug the code and make sure its calling only once .

Comment: If it is called multiple times you could use `if (detectDeath() && !playerDead)` then set `playerDead = true` before showing the dialog.

Comment: You can include a boolean to detect whether a dialog is visible or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I just introduce the variable `dead` to keep track of the dialog. This is to prevent the program from going through the whole process of creating new dialogs, which may cause an OOM exception that can crash your program.

```
class SnakeView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    boolean dead = false;
    public SnakeView(Context context, Point size){
        super(context);
        handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());

        mContext = context;

        mScreenWidth = size.x;
        mScreenHeight = size.y;

        mBlockSize = mScreenWidth / NUM_BLOCKS_WIDE;
        mNumBlocksHigh = ((mScreenHeight)) / mBlockSize;

        loadSound();

        mHolder = getHolder();
        mPaint = new Paint();

        mSnakeXs = new int[200];
        mSnakeYs = new int[200];

        startGame();
    }
    public void updateGame(){
        if (mSnakeXs[0]== mMouseXs && mSnakeYs[0] == mMouseYs){
            eatMouse();
        }

        moveSnake();
        if (detectDeath()&& !dead){
            mSoundPool.play(mDead_sound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setTitle("Game Over!")
                    .setMessage("Your score: " + mScore + "!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("New", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, SnakeActivity.class);
                            mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Start.class);
                            mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
    dead = true;
                    alertDialogBuilder.show();
                }
            });


        }


    }
    private void runOnUiThread(Runnable r){
        handler.post(r);
    }

      }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know whether context.getMainLooper() is looping everything or your runnable logic is just looping back on itself, but you could declare a Boolean in your class hasDialogBeenShown, set it to false in SnakeView, and then set your run() code to this:

```
public void run(){
    if(!hasDialogBeenShown){
        alertDialogBuilder.show();
        hasDialogBeenShown=true;
    }
}
```

Something like this should "solve" your problem, but why does alertDialogBuilder.show() have to be in a runnable? and why does it have to runOnUiThread?

Comment: Any other way didn't even show a dialog. This was the only way i found that worked. Well almost worked :).

Answer (score 0):

delete this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
    public void run() {
        alertDialogBuilder.show();
    }
});
```

put this:

```
final AlertDialog dialog2 = alertDialogBuilder.create();
dialog2.show();
```

Comment: you shouldn't need another boolean, your detectDeath() will return true or false, so don't use dead